# Memory issues on low end devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory, crash, textures

Our game is designed in 1.5k resolution, so max size of image covering the screen is 1536*1152. There are around 600-900 textures of varying sizes per scene in our game which run without crashes on devices having more than 1.5GB RAM. The game crashes due to less memory on devices which have RAM lower than 1.5 GB. Currently the game needs around 800 MB to 1.1 GB of free RAM to work.

In future, the number of textures to be loaded per scene are going to be increased.
What steps can we take so that the image quality doesn't reduce in high resolution devices and also support low end devices which have RAM as low as 1 GB.

Comment: Its a preview package but maybe you want to check Adaptive Performance. 

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.adaptiveperformance@1.0/manual/index.html#installing-adaptive-performance

Comment: The easiest way for you do to this would be making smaller scenes. Unity allows for multiple scenes to be loaded simultaneously, this would allow you to reduce the number of textures tremendously but still give the player a seamless playing experience. Another way you can do this is by zoning your current scene and using a dynamic asset loader. This can be done with a texture manager holding all of the texture names within a dictionary along with a memory location. Your render objects then call their corresponding textures from the dictionary.

Comment: How about texture atlases?